# C# - MEF with thread in .dll

Tags: c#, multithreading, mef

I'am developping an application with MEF to manage some plugin.
Inside this plugin, they are some thread. When plugin return my DataTable to the main program, the plugin is running (in my opinion because of the thread).

What can I do to stop plugin to run when I receive my datatable ?

Code of main program :

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Protocol.Value.RequestToMDE(CurrentLineOfBDDReceivedFromGeneral[0].ToString()));
DataBeforeTraitement = task.Result;
```

Is the MEF unload the dll automatically when I receive the result ?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the `Task.Result` waits until the task finishes its execution. This means that when you receive the `.Result`, the thread is "already dead".

(Actually, it's not dead, just probably returned to the thread pool but you don't need to care about that. Usually.)